# trying to reverse the string using pointers

Tags: c++, eclipse-cdt

I am teaching myself c++ and working on pointers.
Following is the function that I created to reverse the string. 
My code actually works but it looks little bit fishy as 
`cout << front;`  always shows me entire string instead of first char.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
convertReverse(string name){

    char *front = &name[0];
    cout << "front: " << front << endl; // it is showing me entire string   
                                        // instead of first char
    int len;
    len = name.length();
    char *last = &name[len-1];


    for (int i=0; i<len; i++, last--){
        cout << (*last);

        if (last == front){
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: If you pass it a char* it must and will output the entire string. Why do you not expect count << "front: " to output only a "f", but the exact same thing to behave differently on the next object ?

Comment: thank you all for the help. but just for curiosity is it the right way to solve this problem using pointer? is it possible to decrement the last address and keep comparing it with the first initial one and than break the loop?

Comment: Yes this is correct. You can look at the library string functions to see some ways to do this. Normally something like while (last-- != first) cout << *last;

Answer (score 1):

To see the first character only, use `*front`, not `front`.

```
cout << "front: " << *front << endl; 
                    ^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

char* outputs the entire string. To display the first word just cout front[0] or *front